# Delete files whose last access time exceeds N days

Tags: bash

The task is to write a bash scenario to delete in a directory those files whose last access time exceeds N days.
If there are no such files, the message should be displayed.

I'm trying to delete 1 file and find the last access time for it:

```
stat -c%x test.txt
```

The command returns a date: 2018-12-01 16:45:30.390000000 +0000

Then I'm writing a current date command:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N'
```

The command returns a date: 2018-12-01 18:39:16.873718766

Now I have no idea how to subtract this dates and apply to all files of the directory.

Answer (score 5):

Use the command `find` with a parameter `-atime`.

```
find /path/to/dir -atime +100 -delete
```

deletes files accessed 101 or more days ago.

Comment: Great decision! Thank you, Michael